# Youtube API 3, fetch feed stopped working

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am using the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly endpoint.

I can successfully Oauth my application, but when I use my keys I get:

```js
"errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 45754353xxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=45754353xxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=45754353xxxx"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403
```

This was working until a few days ago. The link provided above (without the xxxx) fails to load in the google cloud console.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check to see if the project was disabled?

Answer (score 0):

create a new project, add the api you need to it and add a key for the new project.
i had the same error 403 but now it works fine. hope this help for you

Comment: i tought it works but after 2 hours it died again and results in a error 403 ..

Comment: the error this time says as reason dailyLimitExceeded,  only a few calls to the yt data api pff.. if it is limited that way why they have a api service .. weird